# How to compress an array of random positive integers in a certain range?

Tags: algorithm, integer, compression

I want to compress an array consisting of about 10^5 random integers in range 0 to 2^15. The integers are unsorted and I need to compress them lossless.

I don't care much about the amount of computation and time needed to run the algorithm, just want to have better compression ratio.

Are there any suggested algorithms for this?

Comment: If your data is truly random, there is little you can do.

Comment: What about decompression ? Do you allow full decompression or on demand only ? Do you care about the running time for decompression ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry for the late reply, full decompression is needed but don't worry about decompression running time.

Comment: Once for all, do you need to preserve order ? If not, what is the maximum repetition count of a value ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I need to preserve order, the value distribution is kind of random, I don't think there is a specific number appears significantly a lot of time. I have done some search, but it seems that there aren't any efficient algorithms for this kind of problem.

Comment: If your data is truly random, there is little you can do.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeah, I think this is the case I'm facing. Thank you anyway, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don´t need to preserve original order, instead of passing the numbers themselves, pass the count. If they have a normal distribution, you can expect each number to be repeated 3 or 4 times. With 3 bits per number, we can count up to 7. You can make an array of 2^15 * 3 bits and every 3 bits set the count of that number. To handle extreme cases that have more than 7, we can also send a list of numbers and their counts for these cases. Then you can read the 3 bits array and overwrite with the additional info for count higher than 7.

Comment: If the average encoded length doesn't come out to at least 15*10⁵ bits, then you did it wrong.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I was missing that in order to use this method you can´t care about preserving the order of the array elements. You are probably right that is the average length if order preservation is needed.

Comment: That sounds right, then.  If you don't need to preserve the order, then it should take exactly 33549 bits -- log₂ C(42768,10000)

Answer (score 0):

For your exact example: just encode each number as a 15-bit unsigned int and apply bit packing. This is optimal since you have stated each integer in uniformly random in [0, 2^15), and the Shannon Entropy of this distribution is 15 bits.

For a more general solution, apply pcodec (https://github.com/mwlon/pcodec). It takes advantage of any smooth-ish data and compresses near optimally on shuffled data.

These approaches are both computationally cheap, but more compute won't get you further in this case.